# Debugging resource file compilation (rc.exe) in MSVC2010 Express and Qt 4.8 (Qt Creator 2.4.1)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, resources, qt4

After reorganizing my source files into subdirectories and directing output like

```
CONFIG( debug, debug|release ) {
DESTDIR = $$PWD/build/debug
} else {
DESTDIR = $$PWD/build/release
}
OBJECTS_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.obj
MOC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.moc
RCC_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.qrc
UI_DIR = $$DESTDIR/.ui
```

it seems that a resource file included with

```
RC_FILE += res/projectname.rc
```

is not compiled into a corresponding .res file, as jom.exe quickly returns

```
C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
Error: dependent '"c:\path\to\projectname\build\debug\.obj\projectname.res"' does not exist.
```

The file indeed does not exist.

If I manually run "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\RC.exe /r projectname.rc" and copy the resulting .res file to the folder specified in the Makefile.Debug in LIBS and RES_FILE and in one of the first build rules it works fine.

So the question is, why is the file not created anymore (it works with the old project with all source files in the project directory and default "release" and "debug" dirs).

Adding debug options to Qt Creator's Project>Build Settings for qmake (-Wall) and jom (VERBOSE=2) did not produce much more information about what goes wrong.

The Makefile.Debug has a target for the .res file, where the source file is without absolute path, but even when I complete the path it does not work.

How can I get more debug output from jom to see whether rc.exe is called at all?

Here is the output when it fails:

```
18:39:45: The process "c:\qtsdk\desktop\qt\4.8.1\msvc2010\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
18:39:45: Starting: "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" VERBOSE=2
C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
Error: dependent '"c:\path\to\projectname\build\debug\.obj\projectname.res"' does not exist.
jom 1.0.8 - empower your cores

jom: c:\path\to\projectname\Makefile [debug] Error 2
18:39:46: The process "C:\QtSDK\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project projectname (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

I have also added the SDK's path to the system variables. I am using VS C++ 2010 Express to compile.

Comment: qmake doc: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-running.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possible cause:** Redefining the build directory apparently caused the tools to use the absolute path which contains spaces, resulting in a program call to fail (but which? rc.exe's`)

**Solution**: No further information about getting proper debugging output of the toolchain (jom and qmake), but making sure no spaces are in the path resolved the problem: the executable has its resource information embedded again..